# Reading and Printing a random number

Tags: random, fortran, fortran90

I have the following program and below the program an input data file, which contains 10 lines of different data. I want to read this data randomly not sequentially, for example, it will maybe read line 3 then maybe line 5, not like number 1 2 3 4... Then these numbers I want to print randomly.

```
 program rand
  implicit none
  integer::i, ok
  real(kind=8) , allocatable , dimension(:):: s
  integer, parameter:: nstep = 1, natom = 10
  integer:: seed, rand


  open(unit=2,file="fort.2",status="old",action="read")


  allocate(s(natom),stat=ok)
  if(ok/=0)then
  print*,"problem allocating position array"
  end if

  do i=1,natom
  read(2,*)s(i)
  print*,i=(rand(seed))
  end do
  end program rand
```

Input file:

```
   1.004624
   1.008447
   1.028897
   1.001287
  0.9994195
   1.036111
  0.9829285
   1.029622
   1.005867
  0.9372157
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? For instance depending on what you want it might be simpler to read in the whole file and then shuffle the array and finally print out what you want.

Comment: In light of your new information (posted as an answer, but hopefully it gets edited into your question soon), I still agree with others; it's much better to read all the data at first if possible.

Comment: did any of the answers below help solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help, please let me know so that I can delete mine to save people from wasting their time looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @IanBush in a comment, and also by @Sazzad in his answer, a reasonable approach is to read the whole file into an array as your program is already doing. However, simply shuffing does not seem to me to lead to a random printing. It is just a new order. That is the reason while I am proposing this solution.
Random means that the same number can be printed many times while other are not printed at all, if the number of print is limited. And as I can see your problem is how to select randomly. Since you show some effort, here is a modified version of your program

```
program rand
    implicit none
    integer::i, ok, idx
    real(kind=8) , allocatable , dimension(:):: s
    integer, parameter:: nstep = 1, natom = 10
    integer:: seed!, rand
    real(kind = 8) :: randNum
    !
    !
    open(unit=2,file="fort.2",status="old",action="read")
    !
    !
    allocate(s(natom),stat=ok)
    if(ok/=0)then
        print*,"problem allocating position array"
    end if
    !
    do i=1,natom
        read(2,*)s(i)
        !print*,i=(rand(seed))
    end do
    !
    CALL random_seed() ! Initialize a pseudo-random number sequence
    ! to the default state. For serious program, do not use the default
    ! use for example the program on the website of gnu fortran
    ! https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html
    !
    do i=1,natom !you can and should change natom here to something else
        CALL random_number(randNum)
        idx = int(randNum*natom) + 1
        print*,'element at ',idx,': ', s(idx)
    end do
end program rand
```

This difference is that the printing is commented in your original program and there is a new loop to print randomly. You will see that some numbers will be printed more than once. To give each number a chance to be printed, you should set a large number of iteration inf the printing loop.
In this answer, I used the default seed for  the random number which is not a good idea. On the web site of gnu fortran ( [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html) ) you can find a good approach of initializing the random seed. It is a good programming habit if the reproducibility is not a concern.

Answer (score 1):

General algorithm looks like,

1. Read all or `N` lines from file in `lines[N]`
2. Create an array `index[N] = {1, 2, ... N}`
3. Shuffle `index` array with simple shuffle algorithms
4. Traverse `index[i]` for each `i` up to `size` and output `line[i]`

You have to convert it in your language yourself